# How can I solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb' Error in Vs.Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask-mysql

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,flash,redirect,url_for,session,logging,request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form,StringField,TextAreaField,PasswordField,validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
 return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
 return render_template("about.html")
```

I use Python 3.7.3 version. I installed flask-mysqldb.This code doesn't work and program give ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb' Error  in Vs.Code but this code work in Pycharm. Pycharm's Pyton interpreter is the same with Vs.Code's. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Who is giving you the error? Is it in the editor or when you run code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to config the `env` path to the VS Code.

List of environments VS Code found.
[image: You can choose the environment in the button bar of VS Code]

Usually, VS Code can get env from `/usr/bin/` directory and from `env/` directory inside your working folder. 
You can create a python environment by using `python3 -m venv env` command

Select environment by clicking this inside the bottom bar( this is only appear when you open `*.py` file. 
[image: Here is available environment which VS Code get from your PC]

Comment: I checked interpreter and its same with pycharm interpreter

Comment: Have you active the python environment in VS Code terminal